# How to search for a number using FIND function in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, function, excel, find

I'm trying to find the solution to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38506123/3397819) and I try to employ the **Find** function to  search for a number. Suppose that I have the following set data in Sheet1 and start from row 1 column A:

```
A   B           C                 D         E         F           G
No  Date        Code              Name      Remarks   D e b i t   Cr e d i t
1   4/30/2015   004/AB/01/04/15   Anna      YES       40239.66    0.00
2   2/16/2015   028/AA/01/02/15   Andy      NO        0.00        2205.49
3   1/31/2015   021/DR/04/01/15   Jim       YES       167.60      0.00
4   7/14/2015   083/RF/01/07/15   Anna      YES       3822.60     0.00
5   8/6/2015    030/AB/01/08/15   Anna      NO        0.00        11267.96
6   1/15/2015   020/TY/01/01/15   Barry               0.00        5237.84
7   7/14/2015   024/HU/01/07/15   Anna      NO        0.00        3822.60
8   1/31/2015   039/JK/01/01/15             YES       0.00        1780.84
9   1/27/2015   007/ER/01/01/15   Jim       NO        5237.84     0.00
10  4/29/2015   077/FX/01/04/15   Barry     NO        0.00        40239.66
11  1/3/2015    001/OX/10/01/15   Andy      NO        33074.03    0.00
12  8/10/2015   001/PR/01/08/15   Nicholas            11267.96    0.00
13  10/31/2015  007/TX/09/10/15   Jim                 1780.84     0.00
14  2/28/2015   071/QR/01/02/15   Andy      YES       2205.49     0.00
15  1/7/2015    007/OM/02/01/15   Nicholas            8873.25     0.00
```

I start with the following simple code to find the number 40239.66 in `Range("G:G")` and return the row of matched number in `Cells(2, "H")`:

```
Sub Test_1()
Dim ValueToFind
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G")
        ValueToFind = .Cells(2, "F").Value
        Set FindValue = .Find(what:=ValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not FindValue Is Nothing Then
            FirstValue = FindValue.Row
            Do
                .Cells(2, "H") = FindValue.Row
                Exit Do
            Loop While Not FindValue Is Nothing And FindValue.Rows <> FirstValue
        Else
            .Cells(2, "H") = "Not match"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Though there's no error in above code, but nothing is found in `Cells(2, "H")`. The code did work if I used it to find a text. I've tried to fix the issue via online search, but I was not able to find a definitive answer. All I can find are only how to use the **Find** function to  search for a text, not a number. Off course, I worked through all the suggestions that I can find like: cleared the formatting from the range where I want to find the values or changed `Lookin:=xlValues` to `Lookin:=xlFormulas`, but they didn't make any differences. Could someone here help me out, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `Loop While...` is using Rows instead of Row

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for pointing that out. I fix it but I still have a bit problem in my code. Could you have a look my comment below Comintern's answer and help me out? Thanks...

Comment: how are you dealing with duplicates?

Comment: @user3598756 That's also my problem. Suppose that I have  Debit1, Debit2, Debit3 and Credit1, Credit2, Credit3. So I need the data will be like this  Debit1 and Credit1, Debit2 and Credit2, Debit3 and Credit3. If the number is not the same, for example: my data set has Debit1, Debit2 and Credit1, Credit2, Credit3. So I need the data will be like this  Debit1 and Credit1, Debit2 and Credit2, Debit2 and Credit3. Could you understand it?

Comment: you'd better update your question posting a "before" and "after" scenario to let us understand

Comment: @user3598756 I think I'd ask another question since editing the question would be unfair for Comintern. His answer has already answered my question, only a little bit problem regarding the output of my code that I asked in the comment section below his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will *never* find the value in `.Cells(2, "F")` because the assignment is inside of the `With` block.  You're attempting to index into column "F", but the `Range` that `.Cells(2, "F")` refers to is `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G")`.  There isn't a column "F" in that range, so `ValueToFind` will *always* be `vbEmpty`.  Replacing that line with this...

```
ValueToFind = Sheet1.Cells(2, "F").Value
```

...works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turned out I made a stupid mistake. But why the data debit with the value of 0 always point at row 2 using my code instead of 3 in [this picture of my real data set](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tr0hh.png)? Other data point at the correct row.

Comment: I didn't answer your question because I couldn't see your updated code - no sense trying to figure out "old" code.